# TRY CAST is available and TRY CONVERT is not in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.5058.0 (X64)) on my server. I noticed a weird problem in SSMS. If I write `TRY_CAST` it says in the tooltip:

> TRY_CAST is not recognized as Built-in function name

and intellisense does work for `TRY_CONVERT`.

When I run my stored procedure:

It executes successfully for `TRY_CAST` but throws an error for `TRY_CONVERT`.

**EDIT:**
Following is the exact statements:

```
DECLARE @var_val varchar(10) = 'test val' --in my case either a float value 
--like 4.2 or characters like **** , \&, ----  
DECLARE @float_val float = TRY_CAST(@var_val as float) -- works but ssms shows error 
--while typing
DECLARE @float_val_con float = TRY_CONVERT(float, @var_val) -- ssms provide intellisence 
--but execution gives error
```

Comment: If you run `SELECT @@VERSION;` against your database, what does it return?

Comment: `11.0.5058.0 (X64)` as I posted above. Full result is

Comment: `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) 
 May 14 2014 18:34:29 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)`

Comment: Can you add the exact sql statements (both try_...'s) to your question?

Comment: TRY_CONVERT is a reserved keyword in compatibility level 110 and higher. Check this by firing this query:

SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '{databasename}';

Comment: You wrote Try_Convert raises an error - what's the error?

Comment: @PraneetNadkar `Try_Cast` and `Try_Convert` was both introduced in 2012 (meaning, they require the same minimum compatibility level). If one is recognized but the other is not, I find it hard to believe that this is a compatibility level issue.

Comment: @ZoharPeled `TRY_CONVERT  is not recognized as Built-in function name.`

Comment: `Try_Cast` shows `TRY_CAST is not recognized as Built-in function name` in tool tip but query executes

Comment: @PraneetNadkar compatibility level is `90`

Comment: @ZoharPeled Check here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
It says TRY_CAST is not a new reserved keyword and is available in all compatibility levels. This means it can be one of the reasons. Can you try and let me know the compatibility. I am really curious now :)

Comment: Exactly, that is the issue. TRY_CAST will work for all, but TRY_CONVERT will work only for 110. That is the root cause of your issue

Comment: can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Run this and then check your issue.
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110

Comment: Ok I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 this , thank you for solving my roblem

Comment: @PraneetNadkar you can put it as a proper answer, can be helpful to others too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 It says TRY_CAST is not a new reserved keyword and is available in all compatibility levels

Which means, TRY_CAST will work for all, but TRY_CONVERT (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) will work only for 110.

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
```

This will surely solve this!