# Query XML XPATH in column containing XML but not stored as XML type

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a column in a database I'm working on that contains XML, but is stored as `varchar`. I can `CAST()` the column to XML, but it's not clear how I would fetch anything from this column using XPATH or otherwise.

`EXTRACT()` seems specific to MYSQL only, and `.value()` doesn't work in any form I've tried it. I'm hoping I'm just doing it wrong here.

In case there's a version-specific solution, querying `@@VERSION` gets me the following:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64)
> Nov  1 2020 00:48:37
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
> Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

A simplified example of the XML I'm working with is below. Any examples on how to extract the values for any given element would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ExampleXML>
   <Version></Version>
   <NameSpace></NameSpace>
   <ClientID></ClientID>
   <ClientName></ClientName>
   <ShipToInfo>
      <Name></Name>
      <Address1></Address1>
      <Address2 />
      <City></City>
      <State></State>
      <Postal></Postal>
      <Country></Country>
      <Phone></Phone>
      <Fax></Fax>
      <EIdType />
      <EId></EId>
   </ShipToInfo>
   <BillToInfo>
      <Name></Name>
      <Address1></Address1>
      <Address2 />
      <City></City>
      <State></State>
      <Postal></Postal>
      <Country></Country>
      <Phone></Phone>
      <Fax></Fax>
      <EIdType />
      <EId></EId>
   </BillToInfo>
</ExampleXML>
```

**Edit:** Example of `.value()`

```
SELECT CAST(CONTENT AS xml).value('(/ExampleXML/ShipToInfo/@EId)[1]', 'int')
```

The resulting column contains `NULL`

**Edit 2:** It looks like the final version that worked for me is as follows:

```
SELECT top 1 ET.*, t2.c.value('EId[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS store_num
FROM example_table ET
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT CAST(ET.CONTENT AS xml) AS realxml) t1
    OUTER APPLY t1.realxml.nodes('//ExampleXML/ShipToInfo') AS t2(c);
```

Comment: @DaleK Added information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query for Xml values and attributes from table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165213/how-to-query-for-xml-values-and-attributes-from-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Also see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72191278/t-sql-get-value-from-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72191278/t-sql-get-value-from-xml)

Comment: @Stu Doesn't appear to: `Cannot find either column "m" or the user-defined function or aggregate "m.c.value", or the name is ambiguous.`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Well `/ExampleXML/ShipToInfo/@EId` is looking for an `EId` attribute on the `ShipToInfo` element, e.g.: `<ShipToInfo EId="SomethinSomethin" />`. Have you tried `/ExampleXML/ShipToInfo/EId` instead?

Comment: There are lots of problems  with the **Edit 2:** T-SQL.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky If you can produce a better version, please feel free to edit your answer. It's the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: `//` is slow, also why store your data in `varchar` rather than `xml` in the first place

Comment: @Charlieface It's not my database. I don't have control over how it's stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is better to use XML data type for a column with XML data.

It is available starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Content NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Content) VALUES
(N'<ExampleXML>
   <Version></Version>
   <NameSpace></NameSpace>
   <ClientID></ClientID>
   <ClientName></ClientName>
   <ShipToInfo>
      <Name>Paul Braddock</Name>
      <Address1>3851 SE 52nd St.</Address1>
      <Address2 />
      <City>Ottawa</City>
      <State></State>
      <Postal>12345</Postal>
      <Country>Canada</Country>
      <Phone>123-456-7890</Phone>
      <Fax></Fax>
      <EIdType>Alien</EIdType>
      <EId>18</EId>
   </ShipToInfo>
   <BillToInfo>
      <Name></Name>
      <Address1></Address1>
      <Address2 />
      <City></City>
      <State></State>
      <Postal></Postal>
      <Country></Country>
      <Phone></Phone>
      <Fax></Fax>
      <EIdType />
      <EId></EId>
   </BillToInfo>
</ExampleXML>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.ID
    , x.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS [Name]
    , x.value('(Address1/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Address1
    , x.value('(City/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS City
    , x.value('(Country/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Country
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST(content AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/ExampleXML/ShipToInfo') AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------+------------------+--------+---------+
| ID |     Name      |     Address1     |  City  | Country |
+----+---------------+------------------+--------+---------+
|  1 | Paul Braddock | 3851 SE 52nd St. | Ottawa | Canada  |
+----+---------------+------------------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to like this function? `'TRY_CAST' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: You can change it to the CAST() function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55789735/try-cast-is-available-and-try-convert-is-not-in-sql-server-2012

Comment: Very possible that even if you  have SQL Server 2012, its compatibility level is below that

Comment: Thanks! I can't modify the database so compatibility levels are out, but CAST() is viable. Not sure why I have to cast to XML and then cast to realxml for things to work but I'm making progress.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the final version that worked for me, and will tweak the data types as needed in the `.value()` portions. Thanks for your help on this one!

Comment: Good to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: Please connect with me on LinkedIn